# file command not found on Synology DSM

Tags: posix, synology

On my NAS I'm running Synology DSM. When I log into a shell I was surprised that the [`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command is not available.

1. Where is the best place for Synology to get it from?
2. Also, I expected that the `file` command is standard in most UNIX distributions. Is it normally part of GNU utils? So is Synology the odd one out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many machines ship without a full desktop computer toolset. Why would you need `file` on your router or on your smartphone?

There's no additional profit through "ships a complete desktop Linux experience on the NAS", but very real consequences of one of the software you ship has bugs or security vulnerabilities (in which case the European Union can require you to roll out a fix in 14 days of notification - that's very tangible financial losses right there!)

So, no, Synology is not the odd one here.

> Is it normally part of GNU utils?

No, it isn't. And: outside of desktop machines, GNU coreutil are a rare find. Embedded machines tend to save flash space and ship something like busybox, which contains a slimmed down version of a lot of common tools, instead of bash + GNU coreutils. Also, busybox only compiles with the tools you explicitly enable. And, for example, it's not that rate that you don't ship a grep with full extended regex support, if the few scripts you'll run on the embedded machine don't need it.

So, `file` not being available does sound pretty normal.

Synology actually has an app store, so my guess is that you want to get it from there. If there is no DSM package that does what you want, you'll just have to cross-compile yourself.

Comment: Additional options: The DSM may allow running Docker or LXC containers. If neither is an option, extracting a normal distros rootfs somewhere into the NAS and chrooting to it might work.